# How to use GPX file for UI Tests only

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I'm trying to use a GPX file, for simulating my location when I run UI Tests. I have selected the GPX file under 'Test Location'. But it's not working. I just get an error, which tells me 'Location not available'.

[image]

I know, I can go into Run -> Debug and then activate 'Allow Location Simulation' and then select the file as 'Default Location'.
But since I only want it to be activated for my UITests, and not when I run it normally in the simulator - I don't want to set it as default in the Run section.

So, is it possible to make this work ONLY for my UITests :-)?

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode 11, you can configure it through a [Test Plan](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10212963-xcode-test-plans-for-ios-getting-started).

Each test plan has one (or multiple) configuration(s) and you can set the mock location in the `Localization` section (you can use a `GPX` file too).

[image]