# UI Test Specific GPX Files in Xcode 10/11

Tags: xcode

We have a weather app and want to simulate it across multiple locations and take screenshots of how it looks (different weather conditions/backgrounds, etc.).

My first thought was to create a dozen different UI Tests, each with a different location (e.g. testLosAngeles, testNewYork) that run in parallel.

It looks like you used to be able to provide UI test specific GPX files in older Xcode versions ([How to use GPX file for UI Tests only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560025/how-to-use-gpx-file-for-ui-tests-only)) , but that is no longer the case.

Xcode 10/11 only have a global location settings for the whole "UI Tests".

Another way to do this was via Instruments and automation ([When using GPX in Xcode to simulate location changes, is there a way to control the speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439495/when-using-gpx-in-xcode-to-simulate-location-changes-is-there-a-way-to-control/11709258#11709258)), but the "Automation" tool seems to have been removed from Instruments as well.

Any other ideas on how to get this working?